# How to make to different outcomes of a while loop python

Tags: python, while-loop

```
n = -1
while not dataset[n] == accounts2:
   n = n+1
if dataset[n] == accounts2 or n > len(dataset):

    print('correct login information, welcome back.')
```

The problem is when n > the length of the dataset I want to prompt a different message then 'correct login information, welcome back.' However, if dataset[n] = accounts2 I do want it to prompt that message. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a `while` loop at all.

```
if all(x == accounts2 for x in dataset):
    print('correct login information')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add another if statement inside the while loop.

```
if (n > len(dataset[n])):
    # do something
else:
    print('correct login information, welcome back.')
```